# Unity: Resources.Load<Sprite> returns null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently I'm working on a card game, I call the cards champions, they have id, name, cost and sprite. I use the database script to add each card.
Here is where I call the function:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ChampionDatabase : MonoBehaviour
{

    public static List<Champion> championList = new List<Champion>();

    private void Awake()
    {
        
        championList.Add(new Champion(0, "Garen",1, Resources.Load<Sprite>("Garen")));
        championList.Add(new Champion(1, "Katarina", 2, Resources.Load<Sprite>("Katarina")));
        Debug.Log(Resources.Load<Sprite>("Garen"));//this returns null 
    }
}
```

This is my champion script

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
[System.Serializable]
public class Champion 
{

    public int id;
    public string championName;
    public int cost;
    public Sprite spriteImage;

  
    public Champion()
    {

    }

    public Champion(int Id, string Name, int Cost, Sprite SpriteImg  )
    {
        id = Id;
        championName = Name;
        cost = Cost;
        spriteImage = SpriteImg;


    }

}
```

[my resource folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0R0F2.png)

Comment: Are the images in your folder `Sprite`s?

Comment: Sprites in what sense? Aren't .jpg used as sprites?

Comment: You specifically want to load your images as `Sprite` type. So the resources in your folder need to be Unity "Sprite" objects. What do you see in the inspector when you click on one of the pictures?

Comment: Oh I see, now it doesn't return null anymore. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In order to load these as sprites they also need to be set as Sprites.

Select them and in the Inspector (the [Texture Import Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html)) change the [`TextureType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html#texturetype) from `Default` to [`Sprite (2D and UI)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TextureTypes.html#Sprite) and hit `Apply`

---

From Unity [Best Practices -> Resources](https://learn.unity.com/tutorial/assets-resources-and-assetbundles#5c7f8528edbc2a002053b5a7)

> **Don't use it.**

instead make sure to

- place these in a normal folder
- select them and in the Inspector (the [Texture Import Settings](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html)) change the [`TextureType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-TextureImporter.html#texturetype) from `Default` to [`Sprite (2D and UI)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/TextureTypes.html#Sprite) and hit `Apply`

and then in your class rather have a serialized field

```
public List<Champion> championList = new List<Champion>();
```

and simply configure these and reference your sprites via drag & drop in the Inspector!

---

**IF** you then really need it to be static either copy it over once

```
[SerializeField] private List<Champion> _championList = new List<Champion>();

public static List<Champion> championList = new List<Champion>();

private void Awake ()
{
    championList = _championList;
}
```

or look into "Singleton Pattern".